# How do different vacuum energies cancel out?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I've heard that the predicted vacuum energy by quantum mechanics is way far away from what we can actually calculate according to general relativity. The current patch is to include a cosmological constant that cancels out with the expected QFT's predicted vacuum energy.

But how do these cancel out? Does QFT vacuum energy exert positive pressure and dark energy exert negative pressure? What is the mathematical logic needed for it to happen? How can the cancellation be done so that the energy we can actually see converges with what we see?

Comment: Related:  ["Cosmological constant problem" and dark energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497785/);  [About the "worst prediction in all of physics": the cosmological problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/659313/).  Note that "how the cancellation is done" is still an open question, and some folks (see the second link) think the idea that there needs to be some sort of cancellation is a false premise.